# Purpose for Schengen Short term Visa Switzerland

Tags: schengen-visas

What type and purpose should I select? I am applying for 4 days of a Young Leaders Gathering. I don't know if its a Cultural Purpose or maybe select "Other" and explain

I appreciate your answers

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: You may want to ask the organisers of the gathering. They are likely to have to provide some supporting documentation anyway.

Comment: What it is the purpose of the gathering? Social? Business relations? Conference/learning new ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If in doubt, there is no downside to selecting “other” and explaining.